# JWT authentication customisation with phone_number and password instead of username and password

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have implemented JWT authentication and authorization in my project using the link https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

The code is working fine, but I need to change 'username' and 'password' to 'mobile_number' and 'otp'.

I have a custom user model like

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  password = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
  dial_code_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  is_resource = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills)

  class Meta:
      db_table = "my_user"

  def __str__(self):
      return self.mobile_number
```

For the login purpose, I am planning to have an otp model like

```
class LoginOtp(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  otp = models.IntegerField()
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())

  class Meta:
    db_table = "otp"
```

1. I don't know if the above method is the right way to proceed with. If not please correct me.
2. How can I replace 'username' and 'password' with 'mobile_number' and 'otp'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a view to accept user's `mobile_number`. Verify if it exist in your `User` model and if it does then use messaging API service like Twilio to send an OTP. If the `mobile_number` doesn't exist then inform user accordingly.

Further you will need another endpoint to verify the OTP user has received. This can also be done using the same messaging API service Twilio. Once the OTP is verified by Twilio you can use this simple JWT to generate the `refresh` and `access` token like this -

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

#generate refresh token and access token.
token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
```

`for_user()` method will accept an instance of `User` model. In your case the user who just verified the OTP.

You can return the response like this if the OTP is successfully verified -

```
{
   "refresh":str(token),
   "access": str(token.access_token)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_phone(request):
    
    digits = "0123456789"
    OTP = ""
    for i in range(6) :
            OTP += digits[math.floor(random.random() * 10)]
    dataItem = request.data
    
    dataItem["otp"] = OTP
    item = PhoneNumberSerializer(data=request.data)

    # validating for already existing data
    if PhoneNumber.objects.filter(number=request.data['number']).exists():
        
        if item.is_valid():
            print("already exists")
            todo_instance=PhoneNumber.objects.get(number=request.data['number'])
            data = {'number': request.data['number'], 'verified': False,'otp': OTP }
            serializer = PhoneNumberSerializer(instance = todo_instance, data=data, partial = True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                send_otp(OTP)
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) 
    else:
        if item.is_valid():
            item.save()
            send_otp(OTP)
        return Response(item.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)    
    
    
    
    
    
@api_view(['POST'])
def verify_phone(request):
    if PhoneNumber.objects.filter(number=request.data['number']).exists():
        user = get_object_or_404(PhoneNumber, **dict(number=request.data['number']))
        user_serializer = PhoneNumberSerializer(user)
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        if user_serializer['otp'].value==request.data['otp']:
            data = {'number': request.data['number'], 'otp': request.data['otp'],'verified': True }
            serializer = PhoneNumberSerializer(instance = user, data=data, partial = True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                
                
            return Response({
   "refresh":str(token),
   "access": str(token.access_token),
   "data": data
}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) 
        else:
          return Response(dict(detail='Invalid Opt'),status=200)    
    else:
        pass
    return Response(dict(detail='The provided code did not match or has expired'),status=200)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).